# Openerp "Save" button persists even after confirming the PO

Tags: openerp-7

I am not sure whether I broke the flow and introduced this bug. When I am editing a PO and confirming the PO (see Fig 2).

The changes get updated in database  however the save button is still there. But the PO gets confirmed (See fig 3).

I need the save button to be replaced with "Edit" button (By default it was like that).

Can anyone suggest What could be wrong or any settings stuff??

Any help is appreciated..
[image: FIg 1]
[image: Fig 2]
[image]

Comment: have you customize the purchase module? If yes, then check `write method` in your module. I think `write method` is override without  return statement.

Comment: Thanks for the help Odedra....Yes I have a customized the purchase module... I will check to return to super class write method..

Comment: But I have checked in online bolt of openerp... It is the same there too.

Comment: What is the return statement I need to add to bring the view back to the form ?  Sorry I am a newbie..

Comment: It is not like that what I explain. I mean that when we override write method it will return `True` but we forget to return true than view will be persist like currently is your problem. So this effect is comes from your custom module. For checking you may uninstall your module or make a new db and than try to create PO and update that record it will work fine. Hope you will get idea.

Comment: I can understand, but my problem is I have seen people disccusing about returning a dict with "ir_act_window" and few other params from inherited module..So i am unsure about the parameters I have to pass back from my inherited module.

Answer (score 1):

In `web addons-->web-static-src-->js-->view_form.js`
**add below lines of code**:

```js
on_button_save: function() {
   var self = this;
   var result = confirm("Do you want to save Record..?");
   if (result==true) {
     return this.save().done(function(result) {
        self.trigger("save", result);
        self.reload().then(function() {
            self.to_view_mode();
            var parent = self.ViewManager.ActionManager.getParent();
            if(parent){
                parent.menu.do_reload_needaction();
            }
        });
    });
   }
   else{
       return result;
   }
},
```

Comment: Thanks Pradeep... I just solved using another set of JS code that simply triggering the save button each time they click other buttons.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behaviour to have the save button appear as it is if you did not click it and you clicked the button on the form.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i written this code for my requirement.Before saving the record should ask the conformation to save.this code may  help full  you to further implements ion of you are requirement.